# Texture mapping from Image to a user defined set of points(point cloud) in OpenGL

Tags: opencv, opengl, texture-mapping, triangulation, point-clouds

I have a set of 3-D points in the world. Using OpenCV I have calibrated the camera for extrinsic parameters.

So now I am able to map 3-D points to the corresponding pixel in the 2-D image.

i.e for [X Y Z] I have the corresponding [u v] in the image.

In OpenGL I have normalized the world 3-D points and defined a surface , where I want my texture mapping to be done.

**The 3-D surface obtained from the code looks like in the figure below.**

[3-D SURFACE in OPENGL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQbxM.png)

**It is a bowl shaped surface**.

Now I want to map the texture in the image to the 3-D points in OpenGL.

Information I have:

**1. 3-D co-ordinates of a parabolic surface in openGL obtained from world points.**

**2. Corresponding 2-D Image coordinates and R-G-B colour info of pixels.**

How would I go about doing this.

**Here is my code snippet for getting the 3-D points lying on the model surface shown in the link, using real world coordinates**

**Also it stores the corresponding (u v) pixel coordinate's RGB colour info in image for rendering**:

```
for (int z_3D = 0; z_3D < 30; z_3D+=1)
{
    for (int x_3D = 0; x_3D < 102; x_3D+=1)
    {
        for (int y_3D = 0; y_3D < 135.5; y_3D+=1)
        {

            //3-D point in real world(in cms)
            x = x_3D;
            y = y_3D;
            z = z_3D;
            object_point[0].x = x;
            object_point[1].y = y;
            object_point[2].z = z;


            //Project 3-D point to 2-D image and get the corresponding (u,v)
            //rvec and tvec Obtained using SolvPnP in openCV
            projectPoints(object_point, rvec_front, tvec_front, cameraMatrix_Front, distCoeffs_Front, check_front_image_pts);


            //Store colour information in the corresponding 2-D point
            //Points not lying on the surface is black
            rgb.r = 0;
            rgb.g = 0;
            rgb.b = 0;



            //Convert real world coordinates into openGl coordinates(-1 to +1)
            x = (x - CHART_WIDTH / 2) / (CHART_WIDTH / 2);
            y = -(y - CHART_LENGTH / 2) / (CHART_LENGTH / 2);
            z = z / CHART_HEIGHT;


            //Parabolic surface model
            float x_4 = x*x*x*x;
            float y_4 = y*y*y*y;


            if (x_4 + y_4 <  r_4)
            {           
                //Store 3-D point
                vertex_obj.vertex_x.push_back(x);
                vertex_obj.vertex_y.push_back(y);
                vertex_obj.vertex_z.push_back((x_4 + y_4) / (a_4));

                /**/
                //Store colour information in the corresponding 2-D point
                rgb.r = front.at<Vec3b>(check_front_image_pts[0].y, check_front_image_pts[0].x)[2];
                rgb.g = front.at<Vec3b>(check_front_image_pts[0].y, check_front_image_pts[0].x)[1];
                rgb.b = front.at<Vec3b>(check_front_image_pts[0].y, check_front_image_pts[0].x)[0];

                //printf("%f %f %f\n", rgb.r, rgb.g, rgb.b);


                vertex_obj.vertex_colour.push_back(rgb);

            }
            else if (sqrt((x_4 + y_4 - r_4)*(x_4 + y_4 - r_4)) < 0.0001)
            {

                //Store 3-D point
                vertex_obj.vertex_x.push_back(x);
                vertex_obj.vertex_y.push_back(y);
                //vertex_obj.vertex_z.push_back(1.0);
                vertex_obj.vertex_z.push_back((x_4 + y_4) / (a_4)+0.0001);

                /*
                //Store colour information in the corresponding 2-D point
                rgb.r = front.at<Vec3b>(check_front_image_pts[0].y, check_front_image_pts[0].x)[2];
                rgb.g = front.at<Vec3b>(check_front_image_pts[0].y, check_front_image_pts[0].x)[1];
                rgb.b = front.at<Vec3b>(check_front_image_pts[0].y, check_front_image_pts[0].x)[0];*/

                vertex_obj.vertex_colour.push_back(rgb);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

**This is my rendering code snippet**

```
void render()
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


glLoadIdentity();                 // Reset the model-view matrix

glRotated(ph, 1, 0, 0);
glRotated(th, 0, 1, 0);

glBegin(GL_POINTS);

for (int i = 0; i < vertex_obj.vertex_x.size(); i++)
{
    //Give the colour info from the pixel in the image
    glColor3f(vertex_obj.vertex_colour[i].r/255.0, vertex_obj.vertex_colour[i].g/255.0, vertex_obj.vertex_colour[i].b/255.0);

    //Give the vertex of points lying on the surface defined
    glVertex3f(vertex_obj.vertex_x[i], vertex_obj.vertex_y[i], vertex_obj.vertex_z[i]);
}


//glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
//glVertex2f(1.0, -1.0);

glEnd();


glutSwapBuffers();

}
```

**QUESTIIONS**

1. How do I fill the surface with the image.

**I am aware that only a part of the surface is going to be filled based on the 3-D and the corresponding 2-D image coordinates.**

2. Also If I give colour to a vertex, how do I interpolate it in the gaps. OpenGL interpolates for known shapes like triangles and quads.

But this is almost a random point cloud and I want to interpolate between nearest pixels.

How do I do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the texture image is shaped something like the surface you want to paint it onto, for example a human face being applied to a 3D hemisphere?

First, define your surface as a surface, not a point cloud. You're already generating vertex coordinates for points on the surface, so just link them up into a triangle mesh. (GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP)

Second, don't apply color to the vertices of your surface. Set the texture coordinates instead. (In OpenGL they're often called s,t not u,v but the meaning is the same.) The vertex color should be just plain white. Pass the image to OpenGL with glTexture2D.

This way you get the GPU to look up the texture coords, interpolate, and fill in the surface rather than writing your own code.

Oh, and you are using very old fashioned glBegin..glEnd blocks. Before someone else does, you really need to learn how to use vertex arrays or preferably OpenGL 4 VBOs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am new to OpenGL....The point cloud are the coordinates of the 3-D surface...I have stored the surface points in a vector... how do I link them as triangle mesh ...because it is tough to traverse the vector as a triangle vertices....I need a function where , given these surface points, it has to return me all the triangles(3 vertex pairs)...I was going through delaunay triangulation algorithm...Does openGL have some kind of function where it can return me all traingles given a set of 3-D points?

Comment: The image is a world scene captured by the camera

Comment: If your code generates the point cloud, you can figure out which vertices make up each triangle. Nothing complicated required. It's not built in to OpenGL because OpenGL is a low level API

Comment: 3D graphics is unavoidably harder and more complicated than 2D. OpenGL is a low level API, like doing system programming in C. If you're willing to dive in, great! I recommend The OpenGL SuperBible book, or maybe Interactive Computer Graphics: A Top Down Approach. If you don't want to go into too much low level detail, look for a toolkit such as VTK. Or Unity: it's advertised as a game engine, but works fine for other 3D

Comment: Thank u for the references....I found a software called Mesh Lab...where u can give point clouds and it does the triangulation...and then I need to export the mesh triangles (vertices) to a txt file...Will give a try with ur references too

Answer (score 0):

There are different techniques to do this if you want to do this in real time search for voxel based dense mapping. If performance is not major concern and you want to do it in opengl application you can triangulate point clouds using algorithms like delnauy triangulation and then use uv to do texture mapping. If you want it to be offline process you can  Use meshlab like software export to 3d formats triangulated and load it in opengl application.